# Sorting a query string ABC order (using Unix-style case sensitive sorting order) with no delimiters

Tags: c#, string

Here is my query string that I would like to sort:

```
string queryString = "Called=%2B12475&ToState=I&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA9fa6986e19f98c3413923a6af1c694&To=%2B128375&CallerZip=&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B1200582&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf1957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=&Caller=%2B2602582&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=IN&FromZip=&FromState=IN"
```

Example results = "CallSidCA1234567890ABCDECaller+14158675310Digits1234From+14158675310To+1800555121212345"

What I have so far:

```
string request = "Called=%2B12475&ToState=I&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA9fa6986e19f98c3413923a6af1c694&To=%2B128375&CallerZip=&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B1200582&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf1957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=&Caller=%2B2602582&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=IN&FromZip=&FromState=IN"

string[] separator = { "&" };
Int32 testcount = 200;
String[] strlist = request.Split(separator,testcount,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] testArray = new string[]
{
   "aa",
   "ab",
   "ac",
   "ad",
   "ab",
   "af"
};

Array.Sort(testArray, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please _edit_ your question and show us. Also, please provide any code you've attempted so far.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list which has the field title followed by their resulting data? For instance, do you want "Called=%2B12475&" "Country=US" "Direction=inbound" listed in abc order?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to perform an Ordinal Comparison on the characters in the string.

You'll first want to [split the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split).

Next, you can use [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Collections_IComparer_), passing the array you want to be sorted and a a [string comparison enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8) of Ordinal type. This tells the sort to be done following Ordinal(binary) sort rules.

**Here's the code:**

```
string queryString = "Called=%2B12475&ToState=I&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA9fa6986e19f98c3413923a6af1c694&To=%2B128375&CallerZip=&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B1200582&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf1957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=&Caller=%2B2602582&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=IN&FromZip=&FromState=IN";

string[] stringArr = queryString.Split('&');

Array.Sort(stringAsCharArray, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

**Sorted Results:**

```
Sorted: 
AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf1957a5a626
ApiVersion=2010-04-01
CallSid=CA9fa6986e19f98c3413923a6af1c694
CallStatus=ringing
Called=%2B12475
CalledCity=
CalledCountry=US
CalledState=IN
CalledZip=
Caller=%2B2602582
CallerCity=
CallerCountry=US
CallerState=IN
CallerZip=
Direction=inbound
From=%2B1200582
FromCity=
FromCountry=US
FromState=IN
FromZip=
To=%2B128375
ToCity=
ToCountry=US
ToState=I
ToZip=
```

You can find a working dotnetfiddle, with print statements to show the results. [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F2VjDN).

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ to split the string, order it, then put it back together:

```
string queryString = "Called=%2B12475&ToState=I&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA9fa6986e19f98c3413923a6af1c694&To=%2B128375&CallerZip=&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B1200582&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf1957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=&Caller=%2B2602582&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=&CalledState=IN&FromZip=&FromState=IN";

var ordered = queryString.Split('&').OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

var orderedQueryString = string.Join("&", ordered);
```

This will produce a string that matches the format of your query string. Then, from here you can remove delimiters by doing standard string replaces:

```
var noDelim = orderedQueryString.Replace("&", "").Replace("=", "");
```

I hope this is your intended output... It's unclear based off the question and sample you provided.